# pass $` value to associated parameter function of replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an expression say

> log(1,3)+4,5+max(7,8,9)

where comma is being used two ways.

1- In **"log(1,3)+4,5"** comma is being used in place of dot(.) or decimal sign.i.e. "**log(1,3)+4,5"** is equivalent to "**log(1.3)+4.5"**.

2- In max(7,8,9) it is being used as number separator. i.e. this outcome of this is 9 ; the maximum number.

My problem is to substitute comma; which is being used as decimal separator; with decimal but this should not affect max(7,8,9). i.e. I need to convert above expression to

> log(1.3)+4.5+max(7,8,9)

What I tried-

```
function substitute(expr) {
    expr.replace(/,/g, function ($`) {
        /*some processing here to decide whether comma to be substituted with dot or not.On that basis I will return either dot or comma.*/
    }
```

But how can I pass $` value to associated function 
or 
Is it possible to do this in javascript.

```
expr.replace(/,/g,function ($`) {
```

if yes then how?

Comment: Where does this "expression" comes from ?

Comment: in Germany we use comma in place of dot.So here we want to provide limited support of comma as decimal point.

Comment: Yes, I'm french and we also do. I meant, is this a string that is coming from an input or something ?

Comment: yes..It is a user input basically for calculator.

Comment: @Brewal  -- if you need to write max(1.3,2.3,4.5) then how you write if comma is used as decimal separator. Do you write as max("1,3","2,3","4,5")? or what all other ways to write it. If possible then please provide me good document reference in which such mathematical expression used.

Comment: Well, it's quite hard to found a good way to do it... I would say to force the user to use dots, or use a semicolon separator to separate the arguments. Like in a spreadsheet. In this case, you would just replace commas with dots, and semicolons with commas.

Answer (score 1):

Your language is ambiguous.

```
max(8,1,8,2)
```

Does this return `8`, `8,1` or `8,2`?

Your language also doesn't look *regular*, so you can't parse it with a regular expression, you need the context. If something like this is allowed:

```
max(1,max(2,3)) // 3?
```

Assuming you can get rid of the ambiguity, you could write a parser to do the context detection.

Comment: So max(8,1,8,2) ==> 8
max(1,max(2,3)) ==> 3
Please read this "In max(7,8,9) it is being used as number separator. i.e. this outcome of this is 9 ; the maximum number."

Answer (score 0):

Try the below using Javascript. Hope this helps you in logic.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/kY2mG/5/)**

```
var value = "log(1,3)-4,5+max(7,8,9)";
var val = '';

var splitValue, appendSym;
if (value.indexOf("+") != -1)
{
    splitValue = value.split("+");
    appendSym = "+";
}
else if(value.indexOf("-") != -1)
{
    splitValue = value.split("-");
    appendSym = "-";
}
else if(value.indexOf("*") != -1)
{
    splitValue = value.split("*");
    appendSym = "*";
}
else
{
    splitValue = value.split("/");
    appendSym = "/";
}

var length = splitValue.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  if (val) val += appendSym;
    var strrep = splitValue[i].replace(/,/g,".");
    if (splitValue[i].indexOf("max") != -1 || splitValue[i].indexOf("min") != -1)
    {
        val+=splitValue[i];
    }
    else
    {
        val+=strrep;
    }
}

alert(val);
```

The output for the above code is `log(1.3)-4.5+max(7,8,9)`

Comment: I want solution in javascript only.Thanks

Comment: Where OP's suggested tags includes `php`?

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam - Sorry as I haven't go through you php logic earlier. See user input can be "log(1,2)" which should be treated as log(1.2). I have added this into original question.

Comment: @virus, What are all the functions, they will enter.

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam -- you can consider all basic and advance maths operators specified in http://www.googleguide.com/help/calculator.html

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam -- so if expression will be "log(1,3)-4,5+max(7,8,9)" then how you will deal it. Make sure I am using "+" and "-" both.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution :

```
function myFilter(string) {
    // save all functions and signs 
    var functions = [];
    var regExp = /[+,-]max\(([^\)]+)\)/;
    matches = true;
    while (matches !== null) {
        var matches = regExp.exec(string);
        if (matches !== null) {
            functions.push(matches[0]);
            string = string.replace(matches[0], '');
        }
    }
    // replace all remaining commas with dots
    string = string.replace(/,/g , ".");
    for (i in functions) {
        string += functions[i];
    }

    return string;
}

var s = '1,3+4,5+max(7,8,9)-max(2,3,5)';
var filteredString = myFilter(s);
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XNs8Q/1/)**

This currently works with multiple `max` functions but only `+` and `-` signs. It could be improved with `*`, `/` and more... You will have to find the good regex.